# If-Statement in C memory address

Tags: c

Well,l I am sorry. I think this question has already been answered somewhere else, but I could not find a solution for this.
I have a variable of type int and an if-statement in C and I don't know what this statement checks.

```
int a;
if(a==0x6634522)
{
  //do some stuff
}
```

I am really sorry if this is already answered somewhere else..

Comment: That checks the contents of a, not the address of a.

Comment: And since you don't set `a` before checking its value... (*ducks*)

Comment: Thats the point... It doesn't checks the content... and 0x6634522 is not a real integer

Comment: @cHao this is just a snipped

Comment: 0x6634522 is a real integer, it is hexadecimal for 107169058.

Comment: "It doesn't checks the content" -- yes it does, "0x6634522 is not a real integer" -- yes it is. Why do people who know they don't know anything about a subject argue with people they know do know stuff about the subject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a==0x6634522` checks whether `a` is  equivalent to the hexadecimal `0x6634522` ( `(6634522)`<sub>16</sub> = `(107169058)`<sub>10</sub>) ) or not. It is checking the value stored in `a`, not the address of `a` (`&a`).

Answer (score 3):

It is just checking if `a` is the same as hexadecimal number 6634522.  Whenever you put 0x in front of an integer constant, C interprets it as a hexadecimal number.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` statement is nothing more than a test to determine whether the uninitialized variable `a` has the hexadecimal integer value, `0x6634522`. It is unlikely to ever be true. Your code sample is equivalent to:

```
int a;
if(a==107169058)
{
  //do some stuff
}
```

...because `0x6634522` in hexadecimal (base 16) notation is `107169058` in decimal (base 10) notation.

It is true that memory addresses assigned to pointer variables are typically assigned using hexadecimal numbers, but that is a reflection of the historical convention adopted because memory address spaces have almost always ranged over addresses which were a power of two and hexadecimal notation provides a more compact representation. But there is no requirement in C to use decimal, hexadecimal, or even octal number literals for number or pointer values.

Answer (score 1):

If `a` equals to 107169058 it does some stuff, but since `a` has not been initialized it will unlikely do any stuff.